# error: qualified reference to 'QFixed' is a constructor name rather than a type in this context building Paraview

Tags: qt, cmake, objective-c++, paraview

I have been trying to build ParaView to test the custom apps examples [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/tree/master/Examples/CustomApplications) on MacOS.

I have followed the site instructions for the superbuild [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview-superbuild).

I seem to have a problem with the Qt part.

These are the steps I have done:

```
$ mkdir pv
$ cd pv
$ git clone https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview-superbuild.git
$ cd paraview-superbuild
$ git fetch origin # ensure you have the latest state from the main repo
$ git submodule update

$ cd ..
$ mkdir paraview_build
$ cd paraview_build
$ cmake ../paraview-superbuild
$ ccmake -DCMAKE_OSX_SDK=macosx10.14 ../paraview-superbuild
```

I enabled the CMake variables:

```
ENABLE_qt5
ENABLE_python
ENABLE_python2
```

Then ran:

```
$ make
```

The error I got:

```
[ 87%] Performing build step for 'qt5'
Info: creating cache file /Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/paraview_build/superbuild/qt5/build/qtbase/.qmake.cache
ld: warning: direct access in function 'QHash<QString, int>::insert(QString const&, int const&)' from file '/Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/paraview_build/superbuild/qt5/build/qtbase/lib/libQt5Bootstrap.a(qcommandlineparser.o)' to global weak symbol 'QHash<QString, int>::deleteNode2(QHashData::Node*)' from file '.obj/rcc.o' means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in function 'QHash<QString, int>::insert(QString const&, int const&)' from file '/Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/paraview_build/superbuild/qt5/build/qtbase/lib/libQt5Bootstrap.a(qcommandlineparser.o)' to global weak symbol 'QHash<QString, int>::deleteNode2(QHashData::Node*)' from file '.obj/rcc.o' means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in function 'QHash<QString, int>::insert(QString const&, int const&)' from file '/Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/paraview_build/superbuild/qt5/build/qtbase/lib/libQt5Bootstrap.a(qcommandlineparser.o)' to global weak symbol 'QHash<QString, int>::duplicateNode(QHashData::Node*, void*)' from file '.obj/rcc.o' means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
ld: warning: direct access in function 'QCommandLineParserPrivate::~QCommandLineParserPrivate()' from file '/Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/paraview_build/superbuild/qt5/build/qtbase/lib/libQt5Bootstrap.a(qcommandlineparser.o)' to global weak symbol 'QHash<QString, int>::deleteNode2(QHashData::Node*)' from file '.obj/rcc.o' means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ../../../lib/libqtharfbuzz.a(hb-warning.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ../../../lib/libqtharfbuzz.a(hb-warning.o) has no symbols
Makefile:2392: warning: overriding commands for target `../../lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/Headers/QGenericPlugin'
Makefile:2024: warning: ignoring old commands for target `../../lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/Headers/QGenericPlugin'
Makefile:2396: warning: overriding commands for target `../../lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/Headers/QGenericPluginFactory'
Makefile:2020: warning: ignoring old commands for target `../../lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/Headers/QGenericPluginFactory'
/Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/paraview_build/superbuild/qt5/src/qtbase/src/network/access/qnetworkaccessdebugpipebackend_p.h:0: Note: No relevant classes found. No output generated.
/Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/paraview_build/superbuild/qt5/src/qtbase/src/platformsupport/fontdatabases/mac/qfontengine_coretext.mm:833:20: error: qualified reference to 'QFixed' is a constructor name rather than a type in this context
    return QFixed::QFixed(int(CTFontGetUnitsPerEm(ctfont)));
                   ^
1 error generated.
make[7]: *** [.obj/qfontengine_coretext.o] Error 1
make[7]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[6]: *** [sub-fontdatabases-make_first] Error 2
make[5]: *** [sub-platformsupport-make_first] Error 2
make[5]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/paraview_build/superbuild/qt5/src/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qdialogbuttonbox.cpp:868:14: warning: comparison of two values with different enumeration types in switch statement ('QDialogButtonBox::ButtonRole' and 'QPlatformDialogHelper::ButtonRole') [-Wenum-compare-switch]
        case QPlatformDialogHelper::HelpRole:
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/paraview_build/superbuild/qt5/src/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qdialogbuttonbox.cpp:865:14: warning: comparison of two values with different enumeration types in switch statement ('QDialogButtonBox::ButtonRole' and 'QPlatformDialogHelper::ButtonRole') [-Wenum-compare-switch]
        case QPlatformDialogHelper::NoRole:
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/paraview_build/superbuild/qt5/src/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qdialogbuttonbox.cpp:864:14: warning: comparison of two values with different enumeration types in switch statement ('QDialogButtonBox::ButtonRole' and 'QPlatformDialogHelper::ButtonRole') [-Wenum-compare-switch]
        case QPlatformDialogHelper::RejectRole:
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/paraview_build/superbuild/qt5/src/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qdialogbuttonbox.cpp:861:14: warning: comparison of two values with different enumeration types in switch statement ('QDialogButtonBox::ButtonRole' and 'QPlatformDialogHelper::ButtonRole') [-Wenum-compare-switch]
        case QPlatformDialogHelper::YesRole:
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/paraview_build/superbuild/qt5/src/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qdialogbuttonbox.cpp:860:14: warning: comparison of two values with different enumeration types in switch statement ('QDialogButtonBox::ButtonRole' and 'QPlatformDialogHelper::ButtonRole') [-Wenum-compare-switch]
        case QPlatformDialogHelper::AcceptRole:
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
5 warnings generated.
make[4]: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
make[3]: *** [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
CMake Error at /Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/paraview_build/superbuild/sb-qt5-build.cmake:47 (message):
  Failed with exit code 2


make[2]: *** [superbuild/qt5/stamp/qt5-build] Error 1
make[1]: *** [superbuild/CMakeFiles/qt5.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What can I do?

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand how to apply the patch that says there.

Comment: Ok, I wrote up an explanation. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in the log:

```
qfontengine_coretext.mm:833:20: error: qualified reference to 'QFixed' is a constructor name rather than a type in this context
```

is caused by a known bug with Qt 5.9.5, documented [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5.9.5_Known_Issues). There is a MacOS fix available there as well, which involves modifying one line of code in the `qfontengine_coretext.mm` file. Your file is located here:

```
/Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/paraview_build/superbuild/qt5/src/qtbase/src/platformsupport/fontdatabases/mac/qfontengine_coretext.mm
```

At line 833, change the `return` statement from this:

```
QFixed QCoreTextFontEngine::emSquareSize() const
{
    return QFixed::QFixed(int(CTFontGetUnitsPerEm(ctfont)));
}
```

to this (removing the extra `QFixed::` so that it is no longer designates a constructor):

```
QFixed QCoreTextFontEngine::emSquareSize() const
{
    return QFixed(int(CTFontGetUnitsPerEm(ctfont)));
}
```

Then, re-run `make` to verify the updated source code fixes this issue.